# Exception thrown in awaitResult when an app is submitted to Standalone in cluster mode with port 6066

Tags: apache-spark

I am working with spark.2.3.1. A Spark app is submitted to a Standalone cluster spark://10.101.3.128:6066 in cluster mode. The app does not work. There is an ERROR in the driver's log file stdout under work directory.

```
2020-04-15 15:30:34 ERROR TransportResponseHandler:144 - Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from /10.101.3.128:6066 is closed
2020-04-15 15:30:34 WARN  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:87 - Failed to connect to master 10.101.3.128:6066
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:106)
        ....
```

There is no more information. The master does work on the port 6066, since the app has been submitted. Why here it cannot be connected.

I find a workaround. I use spark://10.101.3.128:6066 in submit script, but spark://10.101.3.128:7077 in Spark config property file. There will be no problem.

Is it a bug? I want to know if this issue has been fixed in Spark in any release or will be fixed in the future.

Thanks.